# flutter DIO getting error while calling api

Tags: flutter, dio

I'm sending some JSON encoded data using POST method to API using DIO which include (imagename, username, imagebase64)

```
final data = _analyseCard.toJson();
    var url = "https://<companyDomain>/api/v1/users/analysecard";
    Response response = await Dio().post("$url",
        data: data,
        options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.json));
    print('response : $response');
    return response;
```

getting this error most of the time:

DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [405]
flutter: #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
flutter: #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
flutter: 
flutter: #2      DioMixin.fetch.. (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
flutter: 
flutter:
flutter: *************** error 3

and some time getting this error :

**iOS**

DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: OS Error: Operation timed out, errno = 60, address = com.companyName.com, port = 54607
flutter: #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
flutter: #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
flutter: 
flutter: #2      DioMixin.fetch.. (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
flutter: 
flutter:
flutter: *************** error 3

**Android**

DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = com.companyName.com, port = 37986
I/flutter (17746): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
I/flutter (17746): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
I/flutter (17746): 
I/flutter (17746): #2      DioMixin.fetch.. (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
I/flutter (17746): 
I/flutter (17746):
I/flutter (17746): *************** error 3
I/flutter (17746): Updated status: IS-PENDING

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please re-edit your question, to be more descriptive, what you have done here is to paste the error logs. The logs also explains  that the connection timed out, you may want to check the connection time.

Comment: can you post the api call from Postman or curl? One possibility might be your backend is not up yet.

Comment: @Rahul you just helped me solve a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Dio seems to works fine. [HTTP Error 405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) occurs when the method that you're using in the HTTP Request doesn't exist. Try running the requests using tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to test to validate if the REST API functions as expected.